# What are some benefits of using NSFetchedResultsController other than loading subset of rows

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

We use `NSFetchedResultsController` for loading only sub set of rows rather than full data in the Table. Are there any unknown benefits of using it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch subset of rows using `NSPredicate`. So it's not really an advantage of FRC over plain `NSFetchRequest` with set predicate.

One of the biggest advantages is that a FRC can monitor storage changes for you and notify your provided delegate of said changes. Whether the data set has an entry added, removed or updated. See [NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate protocol reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html).

It also has built-in caching mechanism. Although I haven't seen in my iOS-devs career people using it.

And last one that I can think of is that you are able to provide section's key path and you get "sectioned" data out of the box. With plain `NSFetchRequest` you'd have to section-ize data yourself.